# stress-ng: Simulate specific CPU and Memory Percentage

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, stress-testing

Goal : For performance test I m using stress-ng and I want to consume 100% CPU of 3 out of 4 Core and 80% of entire memory for 30 min (this is very extreme test condition). And I have few other scenario.

I have tried with the command:

`stress-ng -c 3 -l 100 --vm-bytes 8G  --vm-keep -m 1 --aggressive`

[image]

It is consuming the all the 4 CORE and 8GB is not getting consumed

How to achieve this ?